# PHP : How to merge and set method from 2 object

Tags: php, object

I have case study where I should display data from 3 table.

1. User_Card Table
2. Card Table
3. Category Table

The query :

```
SELECT user_card_id, card_name, category FROM .... WHERE...
```

The query going well...

But when I try to set the selected data on setter, I have a little problem..
this is my code when I try to set.

```
                $cards = array();
                while($stmt->fetch())
                {   
                    $card = new UserCard();
                    $card->setUserCardId($user_card_id);
                    $card->setCardName($card_name);
                    $card->setCategory($category);
                    array_push($cards, $card);
                }

                $stmt->close();
                return $cards;
```

The code hint error because `setCardName()` and `setCategory()` is not on `UserCard()` object.

is that any way to do this without doing inheritance in UserCard object ?

update :
**setCategory() is a member in Category Class

setCardName() is a member in Card Class
should I merge it ?**

Comment: If I get it right you are trying to use `setCardName()` method which isn't implemented in UserCard Object?

Comment: If the method doesnt exist, what would you expect to happen? Probably you can use composition instead of inheritance, but without knowing what you are trying to achieve its not really possible to help

Comment: @violator667 : yes, you are right, because setCardName() is not a member in UserCard object

Comment: @Steve : what do you mean ? I have Category object and Card object, should I merge them ?

Comment: So if the method isn't implemented in object how can you use it? If your pet cant do rollover trick you could beg it for a week and it will not rollover or you could teach the pet the trick ;-) as you prefer

Comment: @Monk probably you can try use PHP magick method __call (it will run for non exists class methods) and create code in one method and place.

Comment: @violator667 : please check my update above, that both method is a member on different object

Comment: @Monk also you can use PHP traits (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) for implement function for all this classes without inheritance

Comment: @stepozer : I already try PHP Traits, but I still search any clean way to do it

Comment: @Monk hmm, why traits is not clean way? What it your goal?

Comment: Its very hard to help because we dont fully understand your program, and the relationships between the objects. At a guess i would say `UserCard` should inherit `Card` and have a member of type `Category`.